# Stackoverflow for Uppercase regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have got a huge issue. I run for one validation in a catastrophic backtracing (http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). But I have a hard time figuring out why. Maybe some one has an idea? Beside that the regex works perfectly fine for all use cases.

```
regex: "^((^|[^A-Za-z]+)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*[^A-Za-z]*$"
```

problem input:

```
"Disposable
BHT,
Tocopheryl AcetateHydrating Shave Gel
Aqua,
Glycerin,
Palmitic Acid,
Triethanolamine,
Isopentane,
Glyceryl Oleate,
Stearic Acid,
Isobutane,
Sorbitol,
Parfum,
Hydroxyethylcellulose,
Myristic Acid,
PEG-90M,
Butyrospermum Parkii Butter Extract,
Lauric Acid,
PTFE,
PEG-23M,
Propylene Glycol,
Glyceryl Acrylate/Acrylic Acid Copolymer,
PVM/MA Copolymer,
Silica,
Methylparaben,
Propylparaben,
BHT,
Limonene,
Benzyl Salicylate,
Linalool,
CI 42053,
CI 42090
Series Thermal Face Scrub
PEG-4,
Magnesium Sulfate,
PEG/PPG-300/55 Copolymer,
Polyethylene,
Polypropylene,
Laureth-23,
Stearyl Alcohol,
Dioleoylethyl Hydroxyethylmonium Methosulfate,
Cetyl Alcohol,
Behentrimonium Chloride,
Distearyldimonium Chloride,
Hydroxypropylcellulose,
Parfum,
Methylparaben,
Propylparaben,
Niacinamide,
Alcohol Denat,
Hexylene Glycol,
Benzyl Salicylate,
AquaClassic Clean Shampoo
Aqua,
Sodium Lauryl Sulfate,
Sodium Laureth Sulfate,
Glycol Distearate,
Zinc Carbonate,
Sodium Chloride,
Sodium Xylenesulfonate,
Zinc Pyrithione,
Cocamidopropyl Betaine,
Dimethicone,
Sodium Benzoate,
Guar Hydroxypropyltrimonium Chloride,
Hydrochloric Acid,
Hexyl Cinnamal,
Linalool,
Butylphenyl Methylpropional,
Magnesium Carbonate Hydroxide,
Ammonium Laureth Sulfate,
Magnesium Nitrate,
Sodium Polynaphthalenesulfonate,
Methylchloroisothiazolinone,
Magnesium Chloride,
CI 42090,
Citric Acid,
Methylisothiazolinone,
Tetrasodium EDTA,
CI 17200,
DMDM Hydantoin    Perspirant Deodorant Spray Sport Protect 48H
Butane,
Isobutane,
Cyclopentasiloxane,
Aluminum Chlorohydrate,
Cyclodextrin,
Disteardimonium Hectorite,
Dimethicone,
Aqua,
Triethyl Citrate,
Alpha-Isomethyl Ionone,
Butylphenyl Methylpropional,
Citral,
Citronellol,
Coumarin,
Geraniol,
Limonene,
Linalool
Pillite Series Instant Hydration Moisturiser +SPF 15
Aqua,
Glycerin,
Ethylhexyl Salicylate,
Niacinamide,
Butyl Methoxydibenzoylmethane,
Dimethicone,
Polyethylene,
Octocrylene,
Isopropyl Palmitate,
Phenylbenzimidazole Sulfonic Acid,
Sorbitan Stearate,
Triethanolamine,
Cetyl Alcohol,
Sodium Acrylates Copolymer,
Aluminum Starch Octenylsuccinate,
Stearyl Alcohol,
Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride,
Panthenol,
Benzyl Alcohol,
Dimethiconol,
Fragrance,
Ethylparaben,
Cetearyl Glucoside,
Cetearyl Alcohol,
PEG 100 Stearate,
Propylparaben,
Disodium EDTA,
C12-13 Pareth-3,
Palmitic Acid,
Stearic Acid,
Benzyl Salicylate,
Laureth-7,
Linalool,
Butylphenyl Methylpropional,
Myristic Acid,
Coumarin,
Heptadecanoic Acid,
Benzyl Benzoate"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Input of course without the quotes!

Comment: How do you use the regex? What is the expected result?

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to do with this regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have a clause that is in the form

```
(something*)*
```

This works fine when the regex matches correctly, but things go catastrophically wrong if one of your lines is malformed. This is due to backtracking and all the various combinations that the regex engine will try.

In the case of your longest line:

> Gillette Series Instant Hydration Moisturiser +SPF 15

If this line does not match your regex, then it would take the regex engine 2,251,799,813,685,248 (2^51) attempts before it would realise this line did not match the regex.

The fix is on the page you linked to. Since you are looking for an alternating sequence of word and then not word, then backtracking is going to be of no use to you (because a word cannot be split into a sequence of word/non-word/word). You can prevent backtracking by using the possessive quantifier (ie. once the regex has matched a word or non-word, it will not give up that match).

To use the possessive quantifier just a plus to end of all your quantifiers, so

`(something*)*` becomes `(something*+)*+`

Comment: Awesome you rock so much. 1+ explanation and proposed change actually did the trick.